# How to display images for www/img in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am creating an app in which I want to create a frame in which people upload their image into the frame and share on social networking and want to store all the frame `img` into `www/img` folder but unable to fetch the image from that folder. Is it possible to fetch that or any other alternative? Also want to select that image for making the finished image .

Regards thanks

Comment: Because you want to save the images of users within the source folder Ionic? It would not be a better choice, save it to your gallery or in your database by default?

Comment: You cannot access at `www` folder in your device. You can read and write into the document directory. Take a look of [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)

Answer (score 0):

I leave plugins material that could help you save and can handle images within your application Ionic.

[Plugin SQLite](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/) or [Camera Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/)